# Best Query for blog posts

Tags: query-posts, query

I am not getting any headway in this one problem I have a separate homepage from the normal blog page. However the site needs a blog so How do I structure a query that will display something like the default wordpress behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Create a blank page with the name "Blog" or "News" or whatever you like to call it.
2. Go to **Settings -> Reading** and select **A static page** from *Front page displays* section.
3. Choose your front-page from the **Front page** dropdown box, and your blog page (the page you created in step 1) from **Posts page** dropdown box.
4. Save your changes.

Your blog page should now display your posts when visited.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page template for the blog and just run a custom post query -

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
 );
```